# Transfer data from html to php page using anchor tag

Tags: php, html

I am trying to figure out a simple way to transfer data from a html to a php page using achor tag.

Code on page1.html:

```html
<a href="product_detail.php?var1=1"><img alt="" src="xyz.jpg"></a>
```

Code on page 2(product_detail.php):

```html
<?php
if(isset($_GET['var1'])){
$data1 = $_GET['var1']; 
 }
?>
```

I'm getting following error message:

Notice: Undefined index: var1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\gaming\product_detail.php on line 201

**UPDATE: Renaming var1 to variable1 and restarting browser solved the problem**

Comment: define variable before its use.

Comment: Try using $_REQUEST['var1'].

Comment: use it var_dump($_GET),  And take me report

Comment: var_dump object and show me

Comment: Try if (isset($_GET['var1']) && !empty($_GET['var1'])) { $data = $_GET['var1'];} you shld be able to use it afterwards

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi Yep i think its ok with this .

Comment: Always check to ensure it's not empty

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi It's not really the solution. The notice message will not appear, but in this example the `$var1` is not empty so it's an other problem

Comment: @MortezaNegahi Got rid of notice but still not able to receive output. var_dump returns array(0) { }

Comment: @AayushShah, try renaming ur. Html to. Php. I don't think it is the problem but it's worth a shot. Your html might not be sending the request properly...

Comment: @AayushShah Make sure your server is started. Check the path to your php page. Try to change the var name and the value. Check all your syntax code posted here is correct.

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi No difference ! Php check the URL received. Not the extension of the page. It should work with html

Comment: There seems to be a problem transferring the data. if (empty($_GET)) {
    echo "Test";
} Above statement gets executed

Answer (score -1):

Use below code

```
<?php
   if (isset($_REQUEST['var1'])) { 
       $data1 = $_REQUEST['var1']; 
   }
?>
```

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you but it seems that the OP is asking for $_GET instead of $_REQUEST.